# Trigger an event before closing the Reveal Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation Reveal modal. I need a drawer to fully close before the modal itself closes and becomes `display:none;`

Current code which closes the drawer and the reveal modal simultaneously and as a result the reveal modal is `display:none;` before the drawer is fully closed:

```
$(document).on('close.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function () {
    timber.quickShopDrawer.close();
  });
```

I realise I am telling it to close the drawer on close of foundation reveal modal I just can't figure out how to do it the other way round. Any help would be appreciated.

Or is there a way to keep the reveal modal as `display:block;` when its being closed?

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery setTimeout method.. we can solve this problem.

```
 $('selector').click(function() {//close button click function
    timber.quickShopDrawer.close();//close the drawer
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('selector').foundation('reveal', 'close');//modal close
    },800);
 });
```